# C# - Unable to read data from sybase database (SQL Anywhere) for longbinary datatype column

Tags: c#, .net, sybase-asa

Below is my code:

```
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=ASAProv;Server Name=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;User id=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;";


        DataTable dt = returnTable();
        lblTest.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Image"]);
        byte[] data = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        img.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\myImage.Jpeg");
```

byte[] data is returning System.Byte[] type with 0 length

Comment: What's the value in `dt.Rows[0]["Image"]`? Are you populating the data inside function `returnTable()`?

Comment: dt.Rows[0]["Image"] is longbinary datatype column in SQL Anywhere db and is holding an image. The returnTable() function is a separate function returning a table